# Lightning:input label attribute not rendered when type="checkbox-button"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninginput

While checking the [lightning:input documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm), I wanted to test out the checkbox-button type attribute only to find out that the label is not rendered when using it:

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox" label="Add pepperoni" name="addPepperoni" checked="true" value="pepperoni" />
```

VS

```
<lightning:input type="checkbox-button" label="Add salami" name="addSalami" value="salami" />
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

So I had to revert back to input type="checkbox". I know  Lightning:input is in beta (and has been for a while), just throwing this out there since its literally a copy paste from the documentation and it doesnt seem to work (or maybe I am missing something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are missing anything. From this line in the documentation,

> Checkbox buttons let you select one or more options with an alternative visual design.

It makes me think that the lack of a label is on purpose. Also looking into the lightning design system, the docs for [checkbox-button](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/checkbox-button) shows that the label has the class `slds-assistive-text` on the label. This means that the label is hidden but is able to be read by screen readers as to make it accessible. [Here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/visibility/) describes the css class used.

I would suggest using something like:

```
<label class="slds-form-element__label">Add salami</label>
```

Comment: the label is there, it just doesnt render =(

Comment: Whats your reason for wanting to use checkbox-button? Seems like you want what checkbox offers

Comment: testing only, as mentioned above, i can completely restyle a checkbox to look as mentioned in the doc, however, I would have expected it to work OOTB (after all, it is documented as such)

Comment: I edited my answer which what I think is going on